# How to correctly do Nil Coalescing in Swift?

Tags: swift, ternary-operator, ternary, null-coalescing-operator, null-coalescing

Supposed to do like this

```
var inputField =  UITextField()
let defaultText = "PLACEHOLDER"
let newText = inputField.text!.isEmpty ? defaultText : inputField.text!
let newText2 = inputField.text ?? defaultText
```

`newText` works, and outputs `PLACEHOLDER`.

But `newText` only shows `""` in preview column in Swift

Why? How to make it right?

Comment: Is the value of the `text` property really `nil`? I'd think it'd be the empty string which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between `""` and `nil`. Your `text` property is *empty*, but it is *not* `nil`. (It is actually equal to the string `""`.) Thus, your check of `.isEmpty` works, but your attempt to nil coalesce doesn't. This, on the other hand, will work:

```
let text: String? = nil
let newText2 = text ?? defaultText
```

So your understanding of nil coalescing is fine; your assumption that an empty text field returns `nil` is not: it actually returns an empty--but existent--string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit

var inputField =  UITextField()
inputField.text?.isEmpty // true !!!
// by deafault it is empty, so i set it
inputField.text = "default text"

let defaultText = "PLACEHOLDER"
let newText = inputField.text?.isEmpty == true ? defaultText : inputField.text!
let newText2 = inputField.text ?? defaultText

print(newText)  // default text
print(newText2) // default text
```

in your snippet newText2 is empty string, because inputField.text is NOT nil

the safe way how to do it (inputField.text could be nil, empty or some text)

```
import UIKit

var inputField =  UITextField()
let defaultText = "PLACEHOLDER"
if let txt = inputField.text {
    inputField.text = txt.isEmpty ? defaultText : txt
}

let newText = inputField.text ?? defaultText

print(inputField.text, newText) // Optional("PLACEHOLDER") PLACEHOLDER
```

As a result, if inputField.text is empty or nil, it is set to some default value, otherwise the text is not changed

Comment: @LeoDabus  :-) i see now, what are you talking about, thanks! i used copy - paste of code from OP question ... edited!

Answer (score 0):

A more **Swift-y** solution for checking "is `x` empty or nil?" is to use an extension:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    var nilIfEmpty: String? {
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return nil
        }
        return strongSelf.isEmpty ? nil : strongSelf
    }

    var isEmptyOrNil: Bool {
        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return true
        }
        return strongSelf.isEmpty
    }
}
```

---

The reason `let newText2 = inputField.text ?? defaultText` fails is because `inputField.text = ""` by default, which doesn't fall through to the `nil` case of the nil-coalescing operator (as `Optional("") != nil`).

---

You can use these `Optional<String>` extensions to replace:

```
let newText = inputField.text!.isEmpty ? defaultText : inputField.text!
let newText2 = inputField.text ?? defaultText
```

with

```
let newText = inputField.text.isEmptyOrNil ? defaultText : inputField.text! 
let newText2 = inputField.text.nilIfEmpty ?? defaultText
```

both of which work correctly. Though I would recommend safely unwrapping `inputField.text` rather than using the `!` operator (even though this is technically safe, I try to avoid using the bang operator wherever possible) - hence the nil-coalescing solution using `nilIfEmpty` is preferable.

Furthermore, you can use the latter to prevent the common (and messy) `someOptionalString?.isEmpty ?? true` dance in if-statements & ternary operations, as:

```
if someOptionalString.isEmptyOrNil {
    // Do something when a string is empty or nil...
}
```

is far cleaner than

```
if someOptionalString?.isEmpty ?? true {
    // Do something when a string is empty or nil...
}
```